# How to import from a sibling's subdirectory using python

Tags: python, import

```
- folder container
     - folder build
         - build.py

     - folder uni
         - folder build-server
             - RemoteInterface.py
```

Question: How do I import RemoteInterface from build.py? Given that folders "build" and "build-server" do not have an **init**.py

I tried -

```
from ..uni.build_server.RemoteInterface import RemoteInterface 

# - shows  attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

```
from ..uni.build-server.RemoteInterface import RemoteInterface 

#- shows syntax error at build-server (for the hyphen)
```

Shows similar errors for these as well:

```
from ...uni.build_server.RemoteInterface import RemoteInterface 


from ...uni.build-server.RemoteInterface import RemoteInterface
```

Expect successful import of RemoteInterface from build.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the directory tree:

```
.
├── build
│   └── build.py
└── uni
    ├── build-server
    │   └── RemoteInterface.py
    └── buildserver
        └── RemoteInterface.py
```

1. `uni/build-server/RemoteInterface.py`

```
RemoteInterface = "build-server"
```

2. `uni/buildserver/RemoteInterface.py`

```
RemoteInterface = "buildserver"
```

3. `build/build.py`

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
from importlib import import_module
from uni.buildserver import RemoteInterface


import_module("uni.build-server.RemoteInterface")
_RemoteInterface = sys.modules["uni.build-server.RemoteInterface"]

print(RemoteInterface.RemoteInterface)
print(_RemoteInterface.RemoteInterface)
```

4. output:

```
buildserver
build-server
```

**Note**: try not to appear in the directory name `-`